# Question about how to think of the binomial distribution with a combination vs a permutation

Tags: probability, distributions, binomial-distribution, combinatorics, permutation

I know there are many questions on why use a combination formula over a permutation formula for the binomial distribution ( for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3420759/why-do-we-use-combination-not-permutation-in-binomial-distribution)), but looking through multiple of these, I still don't fully get the explanations. I was wondering if the following is a way to explain why we use a combination formula over the permutation to count the number of ways to arrange x successes in n trials.

Starting with an example of flipping a coin 4 times, and say a success is getting a heads. I think the confusion for me and many others comes in the fact that combinations mean 'order does not matter', but looking at say getting 2 successes, HHTT and HTHT are different, and so in some sense 'order' does seem to matter. But of course, trivially, the combination formula gives correctly 6 different ways to rearrange the 2 successes, and the permutation gives 12. So this seems very perplexing.

So I was wondering, is the way to think about this as, there is a 'population' we can draw from, where there is a success on each of the 4 flips. So S1, S2, S3,S4 ; where S1 means success (or heads) on the first flip, S2 means success (heads) on the second flip and so forth. Then what the binomial distribution is doing is thinking of the number of ways to order this population of possible successes in two spots? So how many ways can I order S1,S2,S3,S4 in two spots _ _.

And then it seems easier to see that S1,S2 and S2,S1 are the same, and S1,S4 is a other combination. And then we just fill in the remaining places with a failure (or tails in this example).

Is this the correct logic? or am I still missing something? I am curious because thinking of it this way is the first time it seems to have 'clicked' for me, but I want to make sure that logic is sound.

EDIT: The logical confusion for me is why the combinations formula logically makes sense in adding up the probabilities in the binomial distribution formula. For example, I know HHTT, HTHT, TTHH, etc. all have the same probability, (1/2)$^2$(1-1/2)$^2$. The binomial distribution then uses the combinations formula to add up all the different ways in which you can order h,h,t,t, and just multiplies the common probability for each ordering by the number of times in which you can reorder them. My question is more - why does it make sense logically that the combinations formula is what should be used to enumerate the number of times you can order h,h,t,t. When I think of combinations, I think 'order doesnt matter'. That could lead one (like me and the previous people asking a similar question) to think, oh combinations means h,h,t,t is the same as t,t,h,h. so we dont need to use anything else, and the probability of two successes in 4 trials is simply p$^2$(1-p)$^2$. and end it there,  no need to add that number up for the  4 different reorderings. But this is not the case, because we need to add up p$^2$(1-p)$^2$ for hhtt, then add p$^2$(1-p)$^2$ for htht, then add p$^2$(1-p)$^2$ for tthh, and p$^2$(1-p)$^2$ for thth. That to me conceptually is hard to grasp, because that seems to contradict the idea that 'order doesn't matter'. Hence I offered the explanation above to see if that is the correct way of thinking about it.

Comment: Why you think $HHTT$ and $HTHT$ are different?

Comment: Well are they not counted as different in the binomial distribution? if HHTT and HTHT were the same, then wouldnt there be no combinations at all in the probability of 2 successes for a binomial random variable? I.e. P(X = 2) = p$^2$(1-p)$^2$?

Comment: I think as a first step you have to distinguish what is the probability of those events $HHTT$ and $HTHT$ to occur and what the binomial distribution tells you for the probability of 2 successes.

Comment: I understand what the probability of those events are, they are the same probability of occurring, and hence the binomial probability distribution is adding the same probabilities a certain number of times. That certain number of times being the combination formula. so in this case, p$^2$(1-p)$^2$ with p = 1/2 for each possible way in which we can order two heads and two tails, which is 4 choose 2. The confusing part to me is why 4 choose 2 is the correct way to enumerate the number of times we are add p$^2$(1-p)$^2$. Why does it logically make sense that it is a combination vs a permutation